# In python, is there a way to make threads that die when there is no longer a reference to them?

Tags: python, multithreading

Sometimes I want a class that is continuously updated by a worker thread that it spawns when it is created. Basically like this:

```
class MyWidget:
    def __init__(self):
        self.blah = None
        self.thread = MyThread(self)
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self, blah):
        self.blah = blah

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            blah = poll()
            self.widget.update(blah)
```

I want a safe way to design this so that I'm sure the thread dies when the `MyWidget` is no longer needed. The problem with the above code is that the `MyWidget` will never die because it is being kept alive by the `MyThread`. I can fix that by giving the `MyThread` a `weakref.ref` to the `MyWidget` and breaking the loop when the reference dies but I have made the mistake of not doing this in the past.

What I'd really like is threads that get garbage collected along with everything else. ie. A thread that is killed when it's reference graph and the main thread's reference graph are disjoint. Would it be possible to write such a beast? Do they already exist?

Answer (score 2):

If you modify `MyThread` to provide a `stop` method:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget
        self.is_running = False
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.is_running = True
        while self.is_running:
            time.sleep(1)
            blah = poll()
            self.widget.update(blah)

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
```

If at the point where you `MyWidget` instance is no longer needed you can call `widget.thread.stop()`, this will kill the thread and allow everything to be GC'd.